# Ideas for measuring the position of a card in a bus (through hardware)

Tags: measurement, hardware, precision

I am looking for ideas on how to detect the bus position of a module (PCB card) when they stack up.

I am designing a PCB module that is going to be controlled and connected to a carrier board. This PCB module can be stacked up, from 1 to 16 (imagine like a building where the base is the carrier board, and each floor is one of these modules.) I would like to know some ideas on how the microcontroller that is in each knows which floor it is on. For this I have a 3.3V lane and a ground lane in the connectors (and some free lanes in case you want to use them.)

For example one of my ideas it was kind of a voltage divider that adds a resistance in series so each time that one card is plugged into the stack, the voltage seen by the ADC of the microcontroller will change, and that way you can know how many cards are plugged in. I'm not really fond of this idea since the ADC of the microcontroller is not-monolithic and since resistors might vary their value from board to board, it might lead to failures.

Shunt references cannot be used for this, since the smallest shunt reference I've found it's 0.3V, (actually 0.2, but since the ADC would be in range of 0-3V,) it doesn't give the range to have 16 different reads.

What ideas occur to you that can accomplish this task?

Comment: What signals your bus contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Shift Register**

Consider using any kind of shift register.

There are loads of ways to achieve this.  One would be with SPI hardware, where there's a clock and the devices are daisy-chained

```
       +---------+   +---------+   +---------+
CPU -> |MOSI MISO|---|MOSI MISO|---|MOSI MISO| ---> more
       | CLK  SS |   | CLK  SS |   | CLK  SS |
       +---------+   +---------+   +---------+
          |   |         |   |         |   |
CLK-------+---|---------+---|---------+   |
/SS-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

The Master sends a 1 then lots of 0.  Slaves count how long after SS they get a 1.

**Startup chain-delay**

Assuming this only needs doing at startup (is that a fair assumption?) you can time a signal going high after reset,

Each slave writes 0 to `out` on startup, waits briefly to avoid races, and listens on `in`.  When `in` is 1, it waits T time and writes 1 to `out`.  First slave has `in` tied to 1.  Each slave times how long from reset to `in`=1.

**Serial ID**

Each device listens with RS-232 timing on `rx` and writes on `tx`.

Periodically master sends `0`, each device listens for own ID and transmits `ID+1`.

You might be able to do this with built in UART (if you didn't need it for something else), which would give you a constantly updated ID register.

Of course this is possible with SPI too.

**Frequency / Pulse width / Pulse count**

Master sends 1 kHz.  Each device listens, measures, and transmits input frequency * 2.  Or F/2 (might be easy in hardware.)  Or f + 0.1 kHz.

Or Pulse width version of same.  Or pulse count version of same.  With careful initiation you might easily be able to generate N - 1 in a natural way by missing a first edge or some such.

You might be able to do these with built-in hardware such as a counter or a timer function of your CPU; then you can use that register as the ID register.

Comment: Yeah, we are planning or having hot-plug, hot removal option for our project. But the frequency multiplier / pulse count idea it's actually clever as hell. I like it a lot, and I think I will go with one of those versions.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I was looking at ATMega328 timer functionality: I think you can get it to generate F/2 pretty easily as well as time it.

Comment: And with good initiation you might be able to miss a first edge / pulse and so generate N - 1 pulses very easily with the counters.

Answer (score 0):

Will each unit be intelligent enough to this?  It has a bucket-brigade bus wire, so each unit inputs on a pin a data signal then outputs that to the next floor if appropriate.

If an IDENT message calling out a particular module is sent, e.g. IDENT Bluetooth, then each module seeing that message waits 5 milliseconds before repeating it to the next floor.

The Bluetooth module immediately signals "Bluetooth ident acknowledge" and does not pass it further. If it took 0 milliseconds, it's board #1.  If it took 20ms, it's board #5.

Similarly the system could send a "CENSUS" call.  Each board receiving a CENSUS call identifies itself immediately, waits 5ms, and passes the CENSUS call to the next floor.  Thus the master will receive census identifications every 5ms, creating a building map.